# How to customize Stanford Classifier to obtain a pipeline way of execution?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using [Stanford NLP Classifier](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/classifier.shtml) and pretty much know how to run using command line and programmatically through ClassifierDemo.java, which is a sample file provided by stanford in the download files. I also have fair knowledge of setting all the necessary parameters in configuration/property file that the program takes as input. With this knowledge, I just wonder if I could meet the following scenario.

I just know that stanford nlp classifier does the operations like stemming, lemmatization, pos tagger, NER, split word based on regex, tokenization, building up of feature vector, assigning weights for each of the individual features. I am just looking for a pipeline way of working to play around with all these operations. That is feeding one steps output as input to the next step till the final output is generated. Also I dint know find enough explanations in pdf handouts and wiki page of stanford classifier and personally tried working with printTo in property/configuration file but still this is not sufficient for my need.

In short, looking for a pipe lined way of working such that I need to get output after each of the individual operations and again fed the same file as input to the next operation. 
Though java docs are provided along with the package, there is no source code provided by stanford in their current downloads. Also is it possible to generate output after each of the operations like lemmatization, stemming, pos tagger, NER, split word based on regex, tokenization, building up of feature vector, assigning weights to each individual features, building up class models... etc..

Comment: If you want the intermediate output or to just get part of the output; and you don't really care for the classification task, you can use the Stanford CoreNLP where you can select which annotators to use, each specifying their preprocessing dependencies.
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml